# How to temporary replace div content with another

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

So the question is in the title. How can I replace one div content with another content for some little time using jQuery? I just have one block with user information that invisible (has `display: none;` in styles and while info is retrieveing from server I want to display message like `Loading user info...`.

---

**EDIT**

Here is how I retrieve information from server:

```
$.post("/getUserAdditionalInfo",
                { "id": pId },
                function (data) {
                    window.user = $.extend(
                    {
                        "pid": pId,
                        "secondname": data.sname,
                        "firstname": data.fname,
                        "middlename": data.mname
                    }, existingParams);
                    updateUserInformationLabels();
                },
                "json"
        );
```

---

**EDIT2**

Here is the code I have for user info:

```
<div id="UserAdditionalInfo">
<ul class="info">
    <li><b>First name:</b><span id="ExInfoWorkFirstName"></span></li>
    <li><b>Second name:</b><span id="ExInfoWorkSecondName"></span></li>
    <li><b>Middle name:</b><span id="ExInfoWorkMiddleName"></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And I just want to temporarely replace div with id = UserAdditionalInfo with 'loading user info' string. And then data is completely retrieved I need to restore initial content (along replacing place holders with data).

Comment: you want to replace same div content in which you want to display `Loading user info...`

Comment: Yes, you are right. How can I solve this problem easy and quick?

Comment: you have more code in that div accept `Loading user info...`? and you want to replace only `Loading user info...` part..is it so?

Comment: @Vivek please see my second question correction.

Comment: @kseen- see my updated answer..let me know if still you have some confusion

Comment: could you just hide #UserAdditionalInfo and show another div containing "Loading user info..." at the same position?

Comment: @Ghostoy I think so, butif it won't force page to 'jump' or any layout issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store the original html in a variable like this-

```
var originalHTMl = $('#UserAdditionalInfo').html();
```

then replace the content of this div with `loading info` like this..

```
$('#UserAdditionalInfo').html('Loading user info...').show();

$.post("/getUserAdditionalInfo",
                { "id": pId },
                function (data) {
                    window.user = $.extend(
                    {
                        "pid": pId,
                        "secondname": data.sname,
                        "firstname": data.fname,
                        "middlename": data.mname
                    }, existingParams);
                    updateUserInformationLabels(originalHTMl);//pass the original html to this function
                    var updatedHTML = $('#UserAdditionalInfo').html();// get the updated HTMl
                    $('#UserAdditionalInfo').html(updatedHTML).show();//Show the div..now this div has all updated htnl
                },
                "json"
        );


function updateUserInformationLabels(originalHTMl){
                if (typeof window.patient != 'undefined') {
                var ExInfoWork = $(originalHTMl).find('#ExInfoWork');
                 ExInfoWork.html(window.patient.work);
                }
         // more replacement logic as you said
} 
// don't return anything
}
```

Comment: I thought to do it same way. It seems like there's no better solution. So, the final issue is that I have original html hided (has `display:none`) and then I restored it back, it become invisible. May I remove class `invisible` in originalHTML variable?

Comment: Another issue is that I bind click on element in original div html content, and it probably unbinds then I restore div content back. What I should to do?

Comment: hmmm for first issue simply you can show the div..like this-`$('#UserAdditionalInfo').html(originalHTMl ).show();`, do this inside success callback

Comment: I managed reseting events unbinding embedding inline "onclick=''" handler. So, one issue with initial 'display: none; is left.

Comment: Thanks! Works good. How can I operate some jQuery actions in scope of `originalHTML` variable? I need to change some elements inside `originalHTML`.

Comment: make that variable to jquery object like this- `$(originalHTML).find('li').text("hi")`

Comment: I wrap all new data replacing in separate function `updateUserInformationLabels()`, but this function doesn't work: `originalHTML = updateInfoLabels(originalHTML); placeHolder.html(originalHTML).show();`

Comment: @kseen let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1652/discussion-between-vivek-and-kseen)

Answer (score 3):

You could do...

```
$('div:first').html('Loading user info...').load('something.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! See my question update. It tells me that it doesn't know post method of $.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using jQuery.ajax(), then this is the way :

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function() {
       // Replace with "loading..."
   },
   complete: function() {
       // Replace with result
   },
});
```

Comment: I thought about it, but the problem is that I already have all necessary html code in div block. Just first time it has 'display: none' inline style and it doesn't show its content. And on complete event I can't replace it again with all my huge html mess with user data. Hope you understood that I mean. Sorry for my english. Thanks!